# Rails4 : Referencing associated model in fields_for partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I broke out my form fields for a associated model into a partial. I want to reference the associated model in the partial but I'm not sure how to do that. `@position` and `@position_fields` are both nil. I see `render ..., object: @something` but I am not sure how to reference the current `position` model to pass it in.

#### apps/views/events/_form.html.erb

```
  <%= f.fields_for :positions do |builder| %>
    <%= render 'position_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
```

#### apps/views/events/_position_fields.html.erb

```
Fields for <%= @position.name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

How do I reference the associated model in the `fields_for` partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **apps/views/events/_position_fields.html.erb**, you can do the following:

```
Fields for <%= f.object.name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

This is because the `builder` has a reference to each of the position object and that you are passing builder as a local to the `position_fields` partial with the name `f`.

Reading through this doc will be useful: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for.

Comment: Perfect! I was actually on that page while I was posting the question but I guess my reading comprehension needs a little work. Thanks!